# Rails integration tests. Testing for actual pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automated-tests

When using automated tests to test that my custom routes work, all I do is this:

```
test "that /logout route opens the logout page" do
    get '/logout'
    assert_response :success
end
```

or 
    test "that /logout route opens the logout page" do
        get '/logout'
        assert_response :redirect
    end
Is this a good enough test? To my mind it seems a bit vague. How could I write a test to explicitly verify the /logout route is actually going to the logout page/the user is served the logout view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you look into `rspec/rails` and `capybara` for `integration` and or `acceptance` tests. These tests are more descriptive and sounds like what you may be asking about. For example, this spec is describing the authentication process

```
describe "signin" do
before { visit signin_path }

describe "with invalid information" do
  before { click_button "Sign in" }

  it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
  it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

  describe "after visiting another page" do
    before { click_link "Home" }
    it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
  end
end

describe "with valid information" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before do
    fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"
  end

  it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }

  it { should have_link('Users',    href: users_path) }
  it { should have_link('Profile',  href: user_path(user)) }
  it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
  it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
  it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

  describe "followed by signout" do
    before { click_link "Sign out" }
    it { should have_link('Sign in') }
  end
end
```

This example was taken from the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial) and is free online. It has hundreds of examples on integration testing.

Answer (score 0):

Rails has testing facilities for routing. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-routes for more. This will test that certain requests route to a certain controller and action. If you want to verify that specific pages or page content has been loaded after a request you can use integration / view tests to verify that page specific data is available (like a page title specific to the page in question).